# JLabel ImageIcon position

Tags: jlabel, imageicon

I have a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`, which I put by using the `setIcon()` function in `JLabel`. The `ImageIcon` then comes up, sitting to the left of the text of my `JLabel`. Is it possible to have the `ImageIcon` be on the right of the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say the label is called "label" - Then use:

```
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);
```

That should work.